# how to find the max value in an IntList?

Tags: list, scala, max

I'm writing a function which will find the largest element in an IntList. I know how to do this in Java, but can't understand how to do this at Scala.

I made it, Here is what I have so far, I think this should be it.

```
abstract class IntList
case class Nil() extends IntList
case class Cons(h: Int, t: IntList) extends IntList

object ListFuns {
   // return the maximum number in is
   // return the maximum number in is
   def maximum(is: IntList): Int = is match {
      case Nil() => 0
      case list => max(head(is), tail(is))
   }

   def head(l : IntList) : Int = l match {
      case Nil() => 0
      case Cons(e,tail) => e
   }

   def tail(l : IntList) : IntList = l match {
      case Nil() => Nil()
      case Cons(e,tail) => tail
   }

   def max(n : Int, l : IntList) : Int = l match {
      case Nil() => n
      case l => {
          val h = head(l)
          var champ = 0
          if(n > h) {
            champ = n 
            n
          }
          else{
            champ = h
            h
          } 
          if(tail(l) == Nil()){
            champ
          }
          else{
            max(champ, tail(l))
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Your second case should be `case Cons(x, xs) => maximum(xs)`

Comment: Because max function is not defined for IntList, define that first.

Comment: @Lee this is not so correct as if I tryto get a max of a list it would return 0 due to case 1 an also case 2 doesnt do anything speciefiec. it just takes the tail and so on.

Comment: Yes you need to thread the current maximum through the recursive call and return it when you reach `Nil`.

Comment: In the Cons case, you cannot reasonably ignore x. It could well be the max. Be careful also that a list containing only negative is not promoted to a 0 mas because of your Nil case.

Comment: @DidierDupont can you explain what do you mean exactly?

Comment: well your code changed a lot since my comment. You had `case Cons(x, xs) => xs.max`, which just discards x. Also, defaulting to 0 for Nil may cause 0 to be wronglt returned as a max for a list which would contains only negatives

Comment: @DidierDupont well I check that speciefic thing you mentioned and it returned the max negative number so that wasnt an issue. Is there a better wasy to do this?? I really dont like using 2 if-else after each other.

Comment: Reading back your old code, I'm not too sure, it depends on what you intended with `case Cons(x, xs) => xs.max`. I understood that as recursive `maximum(xs)`, which discard x, and the recursion would end with `Nil => 0` as the final case. I post a solution with pattern matching, closer to your original one, and much shorter than your current one.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching would make it much shorter :

```
def maximum(l: IntList) : Int = l match {
   case Cons(singleValue, Nil) => singleValue
   case Nil() => // you decide, 0, the min value of ints, throw....
   case Cons(head, tail) => 
      val maxOfTail = maximum(tail)
      if(maxOfTail > head) maxOfTail else head
}
```

minor notes:

- you can change case class Nil() to case object Nil
- the last two lines should be just `head max maximum(tail)`, or `head.max(maximum(tail))`, whichever you are more comfortable with (they are the same thing).

This is just a starting point, as you learn further, you will find that my method not being tail-recursive is not too good. You might also consider whether you could return an Option to account for the empty list case. Also, notice that implementation of maximum, minimum, sum, product... are very similar, and try to factor that out.